# some questions on exponential tilting

Tags: probability

consider a random variable $X$ on a probability space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\operatorname{P})$ with distribution function $F$. let

$$ \varphi(t):= \operatorname{E}\mathrm{e}^{tX}<\infty,\quad t\in\mathbb{R}. $$

define the exponentially tilted measure of $X$ in $t_0$, given by its distribution function, as

$$ \hat{F}_{t_0}(x):= \frac{1}{\varphi(t_0)}\int_{-\infty}^x \mathrm{e}^{t_0 y}\,\mathrm{d}F(y). $$

what is the intuition behind this definition? what is meant by *tilting* a measure? given that $X$ has a density $f$, can one, in general, say something about the shape of the exponentially tilted density

$$\hat{f}_{t_0}(x)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t_0 x}f(x)}{\varphi(t_0)}?$$

besides, the exponentially tilted measure is uniquely determined by $\hat{F}_{t_0}$. is there always a random variable $\hat{X}$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\operatorname{P})$ whose distribution function just is $\hat{F}_{t_0}$?

i'm only familiar with considering the identity on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\operatorname{P}_{t_0})$, where $P_{t_0}$ is the lebesgue stieltjes measure related to $\hat{F}_{t_0}$, or choosing the generalised inverse on $((0,1),\mathcal{B}((0,1)),\lambda)$.

i'd appreciate some comments or references.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Of course once you know $\hat F$ is the cdf of a probability measure, you should know there are random variables distributed that way: this is not a special large-deviations mystery but a general probability theory fact.  As for your quest for the *meaning* of tilting: it is a tool for sloshing the bulk of the probability mass to near some region of interest in sample space.  I think of tilting as a useful technical trick, whose justification lies in its applications.

Comment: @kimchilover, thanks for your thoughts on tilting. i was just wondering if one can define $\hat{X}$ on the probability space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\operatorname{P})$ on which $X$ is defined? as pointed out, i'm aware of constructing a random variable with given distribution on a particular probability space.